# Code for controlling lighting through the USB using a PIC?

Tags: c#, usb, hardware, microcontroller, pic

I am looking for some code as I don't really wanna get into the details at the hardware end of it . I plan on building a project where I can control some led lighting through the USB port .  I've been told one way to do this is to use a PIC microcontroller (the 18f series has usb functionality built in ) . The only problem is I have to read a great deal into Microchip's libraries to be able to do anything remotely productive, which defeats the whole point as I'm not looking to study the architecture of the USB in any detail . I can program in C/C++/C#/Java . I do understand ALP code(8086) but I don't look forward to it . I know there has to be a way for this to happen . I'm looking for code wherein I could just make some changes in the code and adapt it to this problem .

Consider this simple situation , when a certain signal(any data) is received from the usb port , the microcontroller sets all the pins on a particular port to say a logic 1, this way all the led's glow on reception of a signal through the usb port .

The lights are like notification led's on a phone . They need to be computer controlled because I'm hoping to get them to work , say when I'm getting a call on my phone (when my phone is synced to the comp ) or with the equalizer on Winamp and so on . Its what makes the computer controlled part important.

I can see that this should perhaps be possible . It appears that this problem is very simple for someone who is already into programming PIC's and also that this problem is very old . Almost all of the code I found through Google(broken links/outdated info) was pretty useless. There might be other ways of doing this , and at this point I'm not too sure of the PIC idea myself .

Comment: Have you ruled out the arduino? It does not meet your requirements for a USB interface, but it could be a standalone appliance that could do the work, thereby eliminating the host PC. It also has a wide following of folks doing these types of application. I suspect much hardware design can be found online. http://www.arduino.cc/

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion and it looks interesting but the whole idea behind the lighting is that it be computer controlled . The lights are like notification led's on a phone . They're part of something bigger . They need to be computer controlled because I'm hoping to get them to work , say when I'm getting a call on my phone (when my phone is synced to the comp ) or with the equalizer on Winamp and so on . That's what makes the computer controlled part important.

Comment: I understand. If you are set on the USB i/f, then it is probably not a good choice. But, if an ethernet interface will also work, then you may want to look again. The arduino also offers a web server among other things. Good luck.

Comment: USB is overkill for this application. It would be much simpler to use a USB to serial adapter and any micro with a UART on it, and you would find the UART libraries/samples easy to adopt to your requirements. Even micros without hardware UARTs can be pressed into service using software UART routines, especially if there are no other real time demands. Then the PC end involves a serial COM port interface, much easier than USB drivers.

Comment: @Martin I know USB might not be the easiest way to go about this but it's the only port my computer(lame laptop) has ! ..   I mean there is an ethernet port and what Jamie suggested does seem interesting .. but I only have the one of those and I'm already using it ...

Comment: @Kasisnu USB to serial adapters plug into your USB socket and have a 9 pin D serial plug on them, so you don't need a serial port on your laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done such a thing, and found the following [article](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Building_a_PIC18F_USB_device) very useful. It provides schematics, PIC C code, tells about installing a PIC C compiler and even the Windows control code. Do have a look, it provides everything you will need.

Answer (score 0):

If three lights are enough for you, you might want to have a look at my project at https://github.com/holgero/XFD (wiki: https://github.com/holgero/XFD/wiki ). It drives a traffic light gadget via USB.